# How to call RefreshTokenAsync every 24 hours with Quickbooks with Csharp.net when no one using the app

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

We have a problem on production that in weekend no one uses the app and so we have expired Access Token stored in the database. We call RefreshTokenAsync method on monday to get new Access Token with existing Refresh token but that Resfresh token seems expired (it should work for 100 days but we get new refresh token from Quickbook every 24 hours instead of 100 days). How can we call RefreshTokenAsync method in weekend when no one uses the app and so after 24 hours we don't get latest tokens.

var tokenResp = await oauthClient.RefreshTokenAsync(refreshDecrypt);

We thought of a windows schedular to run every 24 hours but it seems windows schedular doen't support Quickbooks call

Comment: There are lots of options. Are you using a .NET Core hosted application? If so, you can consider a background service: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio. There are also 3rd party scheduling packages like Hangfire and Quartz that may be useful. Finally, the old-school way to do scheduled tasks was to implement an HTTP endpoint to run the tasks and hit that from Windows scheduler.

Answer (score 2):

It is not necessary to call the API every 24 hours; as you noted, the refresh token is good for 100 days.

However, the 100 day window only applies to *unused* RefreshTokens. RefreshToken expiration works like movie rentals from a streaming service: after renting, the viewer has 30 days to watch the movie. Once they actually start watching it though, they only have 48 hours to finish it before it disappears. That is to say, the 30-day window is replaced by a 48 hour window.

A critical (and not well-documented) step to using the RefreshToken is to replace the RefreshToken used in the call with the RefreshToken returned by Intuit in the response. Since the RefreshToken may or may not have actually changed, it's a good practice to just store the new value every time regardless. This way, you'll be getting a "new" token every time you make a call, and *that* token actually will be good for 100 days (or until you make another call and replace it). As long as you store the new RefreshToken value each time you make a call, you'll be able to go much longer than a weekend without making any calls at all.